# Liferay: what is the default approach for logging in Liferay?

Tags: logging, liferay

By development of portlets, hooks etc. I have seen different approaches for logging in Liferay. Is there default logging approach - The Liferay Way - that I can use.

1.How to initialize the logger?

2.How to config the logging levels?

I have seen that the logging level can be modified direct in Liferay - Control Panel, is it good? How can I combine it with config file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the basic logging information you need in [Liferay Documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/liferay-s-logging-syst-5).

Summarized: you should instantiate your Log4j Log object through LogFactory, identified by the current class name, then enable that log category on the control panels "Log level" settings tab.

Answer (score 1):

Logging comes ready to go out of the box.

Inside your class variable declarations use this:

```
private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(name-of-class.class);
```

Then down in your code use this to output to the catalina.out file in liferay/tomcat/logs

```
     log.info("Some info you want to see");
```

Or

```
     log.error("This error was thrown!");
```