# Logger in Liferay is not working

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, liferay, portlet

I'm using Liferay 6.20 with a tomcat.

According to this post: [Liferay: what is the default approach for logging in Liferay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784183/liferay-what-is-the-default-approach-for-logging-in-liferay) I've added a logger to my basic portlet class like this:

```
package mypackage.katalog;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

/**
 * Portlet implementation class KatalogUslugPortlet
 */
public class KatalogUslugPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    private static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(KatalogUslugPortlet.class);

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

        testLogger();

        super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }

    private void testLogger() {
        System.out.print("SYSTEM_OUT!!!");

        _log.info("INFO!!!");
        _log.debug("DEBUG!!!");
        _log.error("ERROR!!!");
    }
}
```

And logs are not appearing neither in the console, nor in the tomcat logs. What could gone wrong?

Comment: try using private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KatalogUslugPortlet.class);

Comment: or refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784183/liferay-what-is-the-default-approach-for-logging-in-liferay

Comment: I'm already reffering to the same post in my question. According to this post I should use `com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log` and `com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.FactoryUtil` classes which I'm already using (instead of `Logger` and `LoggerFactory` you mentioned). So now I'm even more confused about this...

Comment: yes that jumbled up...i am using sl4j for LOGGER and missed out the link in your question.

Comment: Liferay portal uses LOG4J as the logging implementation. According to this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/108683/slf4j-vs-log4j-which-one-to-prefer SL4J is just an abstraction layer for loggers. Could you then tell me which logger are you using for the implementation? Is it LOG4J or maybe Logback? And are you using your logger in **Liferay** project?

Comment: have you enabled logger(debug,info..)?

Comment: `log4j.properties` file is automatically created in `(...)\katalog-uslug-portlet\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties` and it has definition:  `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] %m%n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not in the logger. My portlet was just drag and dropped into my site and I thought that `processAction(...)` was the method that was called after each site refresh. In fact it should have look use `doView(...)` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

    testLogger();

    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Liferay logger does not work in this way, you can login with the Liferay admin, go to Admin -> Control Panel -> Server Administration -> Log Levels - > Add Category.

There add the category `mypackage.katalog`, and set the level `All`.

Now, when you go to the portlet, you will see all the logs. Remember, once you restart the server, you have to do this process again!

Comment: I've tried to add the category in Server Administration panel with the level `All` but logs are still not showing...

Comment: I've found answer to my problem but I wanted to thank you for the info that Categories should've been added after each server refresh. I didn't know that. :)

Comment: I told you that! :) every restart need to add the category again! please mark my answer as "the answer" :)

Comment: But it wasn't my problem. ;) I've tried adding logger to category before and it didn't solve my issue. I wrote what was my problem in a new post below. I just wanted to thank you in additional comment as I didn't know about the need of add the category after each server restart. Your post might not be the answer but tt certainly was valuable. You have my upvote and thanks! ;)